# Radical ideal and repeated roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x)$ be a nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Prove that $<f(x)> 
\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is a radical ideal iff $f(x)$ has no repeated roots.

For one side, I assumed that if $f(x)$ has no repeated roots then
we can write $f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) \cdot \cdot (x-\alpha_n)$.
Now we want to show that if there is a polynomial $g^m \in <f(x)>$ then $g(x)$ is also in $<f(x)>$. Clearly $f$ divides $g^m$ and some of the roots of $g^m$ are same as f.

After this I am stuck, any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If $g^m = hf$ for some polynomial $h$, then each $\alpha_i$ must be a root of $g^m$. Since $\Bbb C$ is a field, that means that the $\alpha_i$ are roots of $g$ as well. Therefore $f$ must divide $g$.

For the other direction, assume $f$ has a repeated root $\alpha$. Then $\langle f \rangle$ is not a radical ideal, since $\frac f{x-\alpha}\notin \langle f \rangle$ but $\left(\frac f{x-\alpha}\right)^2 = f\cdot \frac{f}{(x-\alpha)^2}\in \langle f \rangle$

Comment: yeah that makes sense. thanks a lot @Arthur. just one question, how does it follow that $\mathbb{C}$ being a field implies $\alpha_i$ is also a root of g?

Comment: $g(\alpha_i)^m = 0$ in a field implies...?

Comment: @Singularityatinfinity Whatever $g(\alpha_i)$ is, we know that its $m$-th power is $0$. Since $\Bbb C$ is a field, it specifically doesn't have zero divisors or nilpotent elements, so...

Comment: yeah so all the nilpotents are in ideal generated by f. Cool, that makes sense. @Arthur